# how to disable cache for the plugin in magento 2

Tags: magento2, cache, plugin

I want to disable cache in plugin. eg(`cacheable="false"`). How to apply `cacheable="false"` in plugin.

I am try this code in plugin file.

```
$types = array('block_html', 'full_page');
foreach ($types as $type) {
    $this->_cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
}
foreach ($this->_cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
    $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
}
```

please help me.

Comment: what you mean  by diasable cache for plugin?

Comment: yes i need to disable cache in plugin

Comment: Plugin mean magento extension or Magento  Plugins (Interceptors) https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html?